# Search for multiple conditions in a bash script

Tags: bash, grep

I am starting to learn bash scripting and thought I would begin with the script below. The idea is to scan auth.log looking for failed logins for ssh and then send an alert via notify-send. What I would like to do is look for multiple log entries, not just failures.
However, as this script greps for Failed, anything after that would need to contain Failed.

I tried to repeat the same part again from tail but, of course, the script won't run.
As I am new to this, I am unsure where to begin to look for answers. I am not asking for anyone to solve this, more of, to do this I would need to use X.

My goal is to be able to scan auth.log for multiple entries and then those have their own do line. I would also like to be able to scan multiple log files, not just auth.log.
Can someone point me towards what I need to do for this?
Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -fn0 /var/log/auth.log |
grep --line-buffered 'Failed' |
while read line
do
    notify-send 'SSH Login Failed' "$line"
done
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. As you are a new community member, please do not forget to accept an answer if it satisfied your question.
Thank you.

Comment: You need to clarify how you would want to scan multiple log files? All in one script? Or executing the script with a argument to scan a single log file? Or with multiple arguments (filenames) to scan multiple files in one script.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was thinking of one script that would scan auth.log for a series of events and allow different alerts. At the same time, in the same script, I would be able to scan another log file, say syslog, for additional events and alert on those as well. Basically I am making a visual alert for specific log events on the system.

Comment: @steeldriver - For this case, using an "OR" condition in grep would result in multiple different conditions triggering the same command. At least for me, the assumption is that Carter would want different conditions to send different email messages.

Comment: @Deathgrip OK fair point

Comment: FYI, on the modern internet which is dark and full of bot-nets, you can easily get dozens or hundreds of failed ssh connection attempts per minute (or per second) at peak script-kiddie moments if you don't have appropriate firewall rules and/or [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org).   You may find it to be slightly annoying :-) to get a popup notification for every one.

Comment: @Cas, Thank you. I am aware. This isn't for internet facing devices. This is more for a laptop when out in "public". I was traveling in another country and when in a coffee shop, my laptop came under attack. I noticed it due to Zabbix hehe. I looked around and it was very obvious who was responsible. When we made eye contact, he closed his laptop and left. I was wanting something on the local device rather than waiting for Zabbix to alert me. And this was also to help me learn bash scripting. But thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of piping the output of tail to grep, perhaps using a regex inside the loop?

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -fn0 /var/log/auth.log |
while read line
do
    if [[ "${line}" =~ "Failed password" ]]; then
        notify-send 'SSH Login Failed' "$line"
        continue
    fi
    if [[ "${line}" =~ "different condition" ]]; then
        notify-send 'This condition happened' "$line"
        continue
    fi
done
```

For the SSH failures, most *Ix systems allow 3 tries before closing the connection. This could result in 3 emails being sent for each failed attempt.

I quickly drafted this as an example of how you might monitor multiple files.

```
#!/bin/bash
# vi: set ts=4 sw=4 noai ic showmode showmatch: 

monitor_log () {
tail -fn0 $1 |
while read line
do
    if [[ "${line}" =~ "Failed password" ]]; then
        notify-send 'SSH Login Failed' "$line"
        continue
    fi
    if [[ "${line}" =~ "different condition" ]]; then
        notify-send 'This condition happened' "$line"
        continue
    fi
done
} # end monitor_log

### Main Script ###

for file in /var/log/auth.log /var/log/syslog
do
    monitor_log "${file}" &
done
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. Could I tail multiple files in the same script this way?

Comment: You can, but it starts to get a little bit tricky. You would need a loop for each file, each loop would need to be executed in the background.
BTW - there are applications like Zabbix, Nagios, Zenoss, etc. that will do this type of monitoring for you.

Comment: Thank you. Zabbix is awesome. This was more as a learning experience to help me learn scripting and to use on devices that aren't on Zabbix. But I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @Carter - You're welcome, glad I could help.